# A tale of two planets : Militarised farmers and industrialised scientists in dead lock

Tags: science-fiction

In this planetary system there are two planets inhabited by intelligent species.

**Planet A** is inhabited by a society of creatures which values **science** and **reasoning** over everything. They are also heavily **industrialised**, **advanced in arts and culture**. They fought their wars thousands of years ago and don't need any military force since then. Even domestic security is not an issue, their automated security systems completely eliminates few incidents of minor crimes which rarely happens. There's no country, no borders and no conflicts. Material gain has little to no importance. However food and water sources are extremely limited on this planet and this planet wouldn't be inhabitable at all if it wasn't for their scientific development and infrastructure. Also they visit Planet B to buy food from them paying by arms and gadget thanks to their technology. They don't want to interfere with Planet B further than this relationship.

**Planet B** is in much better shape when it comes to supporting **life**. **Food** sources are **abundant**, even much more than needed for its **over populated** inhabitants and they are also farming heavily. The only threat to the society inhabiting this planet is themselves. They simply can't stop warring and **crime** rates are also high. They also trade with Planet A. Planet A depends on their valuable food exports. However they don't have the technology to visit Planet A on their own. Even though Planet A arranges diplomatic visits and their traders visit Planet B for exchange of food, supplies and gadgets, Planet A does not share its technology of space travel with Planet B for security reasons.

Planet B envies and hates Planet A, blames them for being evil trading aliens. They are hated by majority and again majority desires trading to be stopped. However they depend on Planet A's trade of medical supplies, arms, etc...

Planet A values Planet B for their resources but wants them to evolve on their own. There's a plethora of ideas on Planet A including total invasion of Planet B and assimilating them but majority thinks Planet B should be left alone and helped as necessary.

Life is getting harder on Planet A as their planet is losing its atmosphere and the cost of supporting life on that planet is getting closer to supporting life on a spaceship.

Life is getting harder on Planet B as violence climbs up. Their society is on the brink of collapse as individuals getting tired of crime, losing their sense of trust and security. A planet wide war can break out any time.

How can they get out of this?

***Edits after comments:***
Fill in the missing parts/flaws in this setup:

1. Planet A can't end their dependency on Planet B even though they are significantly advanced in tech. Why can't their produce more food in an artificial environment? What other dependencies they might have?
2. Why doesn't Planet A simply invade/dominate Planet B?
3. Can Planet B has any other advantage/resource that Planet A simply
   have no other option but trade?

***Edit:
There are major flaws in this briefing setup as pointed out in the comments. I think I overdid it in a flawed way while trying to explain the initial conflict.***

Comment: Hello and welcome. This looks like you have your world built pretty well, and need a help with your story. This would be off topic here. If that's the case, see writers stack exchange. If you need answer about building your world, please edit and clarify.

Comment: If planet B isn't short of food, how are they overpopulated?  It sounds more like they are simply densely populated like Japan.

Comment: You have a major flaw in your story. Planet A (the advanced) would be easily able to produce food using their tech. Even in our world we have the ability to do indoor farming, in completely controlled environments. An advanced space society would not have any problem producing food in huge factories. Their atmosphere is another issue all-together though. Also, it sounds like Planet B could solve their problems if one nation was able to beat every other and control it all, or they eventually settled much like earth has done into a "peace" of sorts between all countries after a great war (or 2).

Comment: Thanks Molot for the help and thanks Inbar Rose for mentioning the flaw. Its actually a flawed world as I was as Inbar Rose suggested. The reasoning for this conflict to exist isn't strong enough given the level of A and B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

War on planet B, planet A takes someones side in it. Planet A can make a contract with some nation X in planet B to aid them in the planet wide war for a trade agreement or colonies on the enemy states of nation X. Problems tend to change political situations dramatically. If it is for survival of some lives, it is easy to gain support for invasion in planet A. In planet B, the nations probably hate each other. Taking aid from a less hated planet A is not a problem; planet A is at least not killing them.